Blazor WASM Integrity issues with Azure Static Web Apps Hosting
I recently published my Blazor WASM app to Azure static web apps. I'm skipping frontend build as mentioned over here in the official docs and publishing the output to Azure static web apps using the following action in yml.
- name: Publish Blazor Project
  run: dotnet publish ./Web/Web.csproj -c:Release --no-restore -o dist/Web --nologo

- uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
  with:
    azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ env.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN }}
    action: "upload"
    ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
    # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
    app_location: "dist/Web/wwwroot" # App source code path
    api_location: "" # Api
    output_location: "" # Built app content directory - optional
    skip_app_build: true # Skip build - optional
    ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

I have the staticwebapp.config.json placed in the wwwroot of my blazor app.
Here is the content of staticwebapp.config.json:
{
    "navigationFallback": {
      "rewrite": "index.html"      
    },
    "mimeTypes": {
      ".json": "text/json"
    }
  }

Now When I access the page, I get the following integrity error in browser console.
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://domain/staticwebapp.config.json' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'Y4zkp0LpTVetcAY96ckDWdIeBi7tMyNFMD5PDHdo+sQ='. The resource has been blocked.

Here is the error screen print:

Update 1:
Tried changing the app_location: dist/Web and output_location: wwwroot as suggested by Aslesha Kantamsetti in comments. But that lead to deployment failure.
Here is the screen print of deployment failure.

Please can you assist me on what I'm missing?

If possible, share your GitHub repo?

I have another public repo with similar structure - https://github.com/ILoveDotNet/ilovedotnet

The Error you're facing is your app location and output location in the GitHub yml file.
I refered these two documentations 1 and 2.

The app location must be the root directory of Github repository.

In the app location section of GitHub workflow file, you need to specify the directory where the .csproj file is located in your repository.


The output location should be the directory where the build file will be available.

Enable Enable configure file changes in azure to allow the changes in staticwebapp.config.json.



I deployed Sample Blazor WASM app to Azure Static web app using below GitHub workflow.
GitHub Workflow:
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_BRAVE_FOREST_0D2BE7B0F }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} 
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "./BlazorApp33" 
          api_location: "Api" 
          output_location: "wwwroot"           
  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_<keyValue>}}
          action: "close"

It Is Successfully deployed to the Azure static web app as shown below.

Azure Static Web App Output:


You are using default build provided by oryx? I need a custom build option. So in my yml I publish my project in previous step and use that output in azure static web app publish. Here is the reference from the docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/build-configuration?tabs=github-actions#skip-building-front-end-app

@finger10 Skip build is only used for nodejs application.

we can also use that for blazor right? I think there should not be any limitation like that.

@fingers10 You need mention the output_location:"wwwroot" not in app_location: "dist/Web/wwwroot", as you run publish command in your yml file, because azure static web app itself run the build commands and server file from build directory.

@fingers10 See this output_location description. Dotnet NET projects, the location is relative to the output folder.

So what should be the output_location when I do skip_app_build for my case? my current staticwebapp.config.json is within wwwroot.

@fingers10 It is wwwroot folder.

I tried output_location: "wwwroot" but still the issue persists after deployment..

@fingers10 Did you remove the wwwroot file in the app-location?

I tried changing the app_location and output_location but that lead to deployment failure. I have updated the question with screenshot in Update 1 section.

@fingers10 Can you please provide the project structure.

@fingers10 If possible, share your GitHub repository?

here you go - https://github.com/ILoveDotNet/ilovedotnet

@fingers10 I will check and update.

I'm sure you must have got something to help me on this..
